# OpenWeatherMap Obtains Random Data

Tags: openweathermap

There is a problem with the OpenWeatherMap API, sometimes I get the wrong data I do not know why. Here is an example:

```js
{
    coord: {
        lon: 106.85,
        lat: -6.21
    },
    weather: [
        {
            id: 701,
            main: "Mist",
            description: "mist",
            icon: "50n"
        }
    ],
    base: "stations",
    main: {
        temp: 26,
        pressure: 1011,
        humidity: 88,
        temp_min: 26,
        temp_max: 26
    },
    visibility: 2300,
    wind: {
        speed: 1.5
    },
    clouds: {
        all: 40
    },
    dt: 1499455800,
    sys: {
        type: 1,
        id: 8043,
        message: 0.0191,
        country: "ID",
        sunrise: 1499382259,
        sunset: 1499424661
    },
    id: 1642911,
    name: "Jakarta",
    cod: 200
}
```

The temperature is correct but the description is incorrect.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: I am assuming you meant "the description is incorrect"? If so, *why* is it incorrect? The link above has the description as `"mist"`, I don't know why that is wrong.

Comment: Also, the API key is meant to be private. I don't think it's a great idea to be sharing that on a public forum.

Comment: Well you can help me how to fetch data tomorrow

Comment: I have the same problem. Too many (US west cost) cities show "mist" as description (or haze, smoke). I don't think that is true I was there, no mist. So this means OpenWeather sucks?